# Codeigniter config set_item

Tags: codeigniter

Eu uso o Codeigniter, e eu fiz uma `config` personalizada e agora eu não consigo setar o valor para ela. Na verdade eu consigo, mas o valor fica apenas para o `Controller` atual. Se eu mudar para outro e puxar aquela `config`, o valor está zerado novamente. É assim mesmo?

Eu faço a alteração desta forma:

```
$this->config->set_item('teste', TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

O valor é atribuído dinamicamente (pode ser criado um valor ou alterado o valor carregado), e o seu valor só ficará presente dentro daquela requisição.

*Ele não muda o arquivo **originial** nem os seus valores que está presente na pasta `config`, acredito ser isso a sua duvida.*

***Doc CodeIgniter:*** [Setting a Config Item](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html?highlight=config#setting-a-config-item)

Comment: Sim, seria essa dúvida mesmo! Depois de postar essa dúvida, eu comecei a pensar e percebi isso também!! rsrsrsr
Muito obrigado pela ajuda amigo!! Abraço